# copy files from Web Application to Network directory

Tags: asp.net, impersonation, network-share

I am planning to use impersonation in Web Application to copy files to target network shared location. I want to copy many files to many Network locations and traffic is high in peak hours. I could batch copy many files to many network locations at intervals.

I would be using following code for implementation
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306158

Please advise me on which LogonType I should use. As per my understanding available LogonType for my scenario are as follows.

- LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE = 2
- LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK = 3
- LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK_CLEARTEXT = 8

At present I am planning to use LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE

Answer (score 1):

LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE should be avoided since it should open a prompt on client terminal asking for password, consider LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK or LOGON32_LOGON_BATCH instead.
If you considering using batch process, the impersonation should use the desktop LogonUser api :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378184%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Or schedule the task and run it as a specific user.

Comment: I used LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE and it does not prompt for password. I am curious about knowing LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK = 3 
or LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK_CLEARTEXT = 8 for process.